# How to assign input id to variable for concat with url api call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading data from api into html table and would like to use user input field to change api call.

```
    <input id="stockInput" value="AAPL"></input>
    <br/>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>


const stocksBody = document.querySelector("#stocks-table > tbody 
#data");
var input = $("#stockInput").val();
var url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0//stock";
var quote = "/quote"; 

    function setup() {
      var button = select("#submit");
      button.mousePressed(loadData); 
   }

      function loadData(){
      const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("get", url + input.val() + quote);
      request.onload = () => {
        try {
          var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
          console.log(response);
          populateData(response);x
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn("Could not load data!");
        }
      };  
      request.send();
```

I expect stock symbol entered by user to return stock data.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.val()` twice.

Change this line:

```
request.open("get", url + input.val() + quote);
//                             ^^^^^^ - remove
```